# How to achieve Snapchat-like swipe between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, iphone, swipe, uipageviewcontroller

What's the best way to achieve the same behaviour?
I specifically want the type of swiping that follows the finger, like the one achieved with `UIPageViewController` - however there's a bounce I can't get rid of.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard turn off bounce option in attribute inspector.